# How do I pass variables between two servers?

Tags: shell, unix

I am taking input from user for a shell script, and want to run this script on different servers.
 
I tried to pass the variables as follows:

```
    USERNAME=****
    HOSTS="**** ***** *****"    
    FOO=$1
    BAR=$2
    for HOSTNAME in ${HOSTS} ; do
        ssh $USERNAME@$HOSTNAME bash << EOF

    #script using FOO and BAR variables goes here

    EOF
```

Login to the server is successful but variables are not being passed. 
How can handle this situation without creating a temp file?

Comment: You should accept the answer that was most helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
VAR="something"

ssh $USERNAME@$HOSTNAME "

VAR=$VAR
export VAR

"
```

Answer (score 1):

Possible Duplicate of this [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/48783/how-can-i-pass-an-environment-variable-through-an-ssh-command) Answer.

In a nutshell: You can pass values with a command similar to the following:

```
ssh username@machine VAR=value cmd cmdargs
```